# mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'__v'}" do not exist on the document "WorkflowExecutions"

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I am working with python-flask and mongodb. Things was working fine suddenly I am getting the below error

```
mongoengine.errors.FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'__v'}" do not exist on the document "WorkflowExecutions"
```

I am sharing this table in nodets application also I have created the model for this tables in nodets. both are having the same fields. I even restarted the codebase and system deleted the tables but still getting the same issue.

**Code which is returning the error**

```
@app.route('/api/task/ping-db', methods=['GET'])
def pingdb():
    execution = WorkflowExecutions.objects(workflow_id ="653224656fd5f59905c58cc6").first()
    return jsonify({"result": execution})
```

**Flask Model**

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, ListField, ObjectIdField, DateTimeField, connect
from datetime import datetime
# Define the default MongoDB connection
connect('workflow', host='mongodb://localhost:27017/workflow')

class WorkflowExecutions(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=255)
    workflow_id = ObjectIdField(required=True, max_length=255)
    nodes = ListField()
    edges = ListField()
    status = StringField(max_length=255)
    createdAt = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    updatedAt = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
```

**NodeTs Model**

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, ObjectId } from 'mongoose';

interface IExecution extends Document {
  name: string;
  workflow_id: ObjectId;
  nodes: any[]; 
  edges: any[];
  status: string;
}

const execution_schema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  workflow_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'WorkFlow' },
  nodes: [{ type: Schema.Types.Mixed }],
  edges: [{type: Schema.Types.Mixed}], 
  status: {type: String}
},{
  timestamps: true
});

const Execution = mongoose.model<IExecution>('Workflow_execution', execution_schema);

export default Execution;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass field __v which create by nodejs model. In class `WorkflowExecutions` add meta `strict` is `false`.

```
class WorkflowExecutions(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=255)
    workflow_id = ObjectIdField(required=True, max_length=255)
    nodes = ListField()
    edges = ListField()
    status = StringField(max_length=255)
    createdAt = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    updatedAt = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {"strict": False}
```